# How to use template matching to identify different size of objects in opencv/javacv?

Tags: java, opencv, javacv

I went through couple of template matching tutorials and I had noticed that most of the tutorials try to match the template which crop from original image. But I would like to know whether is it possible to identify similar objects with different widths and heights ?

In my project I have following type of image which I generated.

[image]

and I need to identify following components from it.

[image]

[image]

[image]

How can I archive this using opencv or javacv?? Is it possible to use template matching for this? Because this objects can be in different sizes so is it possible to use it? Please can some one give simple code example to identify this objects ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure that it helps you in real situation, but simple threshold did the trick on your input image:

[image]

Code:

```
Mat src = imread("input.jpg"), tmp;
cvtColor(src, tmp, CV_BGR2GRAY);
threshold(tmp, tmp, 200, 255, THRESH_BINARY);
```

Comment: Actually it solve this situation but I need to get the universal solution which identify those objects in any condition. Another thing is I need to identify those objects separately and need to get x,y coordinates of those objects as well.

Comment: Could you please tell me how to get x,y coordinates of extracted objects as your solution ?

Comment: I'm strongly recommend reading OpenCV docs before asking such basic question. You have to use `findContours` function and after this find center of each contour.

Answer (score 1):

Template matching/pattern recognition would work for this. However, as far as i know, openCV's template matching does not use scaling or rotation. It just finds the most likely position by "sliding" the template over the image and looking for the smallest difference.
Personally i'd use HALCON for this, but that's a pretty expensive program/package.

Comment: But when I try to use it it didn't give exact result for all the objects. It identify the object that I crop to use as template but other object didn't identified. Could you please give some example code ?